# I design a div in photoshop, but the html is messy

Tags: html, css

I design this div in the photoshop where it looks well, but my html is messy. Here is the design:

[image: Div design works well]

And this is what happend when i tried to write html and css of it:
[image: Not working properly]

As you can see, the images (left and right) are not shown, and the text is up.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7a2cK/)

This is the html:

```
<body>
<div id="alert_strip" class="" style="position: fixed; margin-top: -76px; opacity: 1;">
<p>
    <i></i>
    <span>
        <h4>פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב </h4>
        <label><b>נגב 299</b> - <b>נגב 301</b></label>
    </span>
    <a></a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

This is CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'ReformaNarrowMedium';
    src:url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/fonts/reformaNarrow/reformanarrowmediumwebfont.eot);
    src:url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/fonts/reformaNarrow/reformanarrowmediumwebfont.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/fonts/reformaNarrow/reformanarrowmediumwebfont.woff) format("woff"),url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/fonts/reformaNarrow/reformanarrowmediumwebfont.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal
}

#alert_strip {
    position:absolute !important;
    top:0;
    left:1px;
    width:100%;
    min-height:59px;
    z-index:20000;
    padding:0 0 20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/images/common/alertStrip_bg.png) center bottom no-repeat
}

#alert_strip * {
    font-family:ReformaNarrowMedium,ArialBoldResized,Arial;
    color:#f2f2f2
}

#alert_strip.hide {
    top:-10000px !important
}

.fixy #alert_strip {
    position:fixed !important;
    height:auto !important
}

#alert_strip p {
    text-align:center;
    width:778px;
    min-height:59px;
    background:#c91010 !important;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    right:1px;
    line-height:normal;
    overflow:hidden
}

#alert_strip span {
    direction:rtl;
    float:right;
    width:538px;
    text-align:center;
    max-height:257px
} 

#alert_strip span h4 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:37px;
    font-weight:400;
    float:none;
    background:0
} 

#alert_strip span label,#alert_strip span label b {
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:400;
    height:auto !important;
    max-height:195px
}

#alert_strip span label b {
    white-space:nowrap
} 

#alert_strip a {
    float:left;
    width:94px;
    height:100%;
    background:url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/images/common/alertStrip_close.png) center right no-repeat;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:0;
    margin-left:30px
}

#alert_strip a:hover {
    background-position:center left
}

#alert_strip p i {
    float:right;
    background:url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/images/common/alertStrip_siren.gif) center center no-repeat;
    width:111px;
    height:100%;
    margin:-4px 5px 0 0
}

.neo #alert_strip {
    height:59px;
    right:0;
    z-index:40000;
    background:url(http://rcs.mako.co.il/images/neo/alertStrip_bg.png) center bottom no-repeat
}

.neo #alert_strip p {
    width:960px;
    right:0;
    background-color:transparent
}

.neo #alert_strip p i {
    width:111px;
    height:67px;
    margin:0
} 

.neo #alert_strip a {
    width:94px;
    height:40px;
    margin:17px 0 0 20px
}

.neo #alert_strip span {
    margin-left:17px;
    width:718px
} 

.neo #alert_strip span label {
    display:inline-block;
    height:25px;
    overflow:hidden
}

.neo #alert_strip span h4 {
    margin-top:7px
}

.neo #alert_strip span label b {
    display:inline-block;
    font:normal 23px ReformaNarrowRegular !important;
    margin-top:-3px
}
```

What should i do to fix this issue?

Comment: Code.Always.Goes.In.The.Question.

Comment: You can start by sharing the code you have, the html and css...

Comment: @EngineerDollery, I gave a link to JSFiddle, please remote the -1

Comment: Still should post your code in the question

Comment: I know you did. That doesn't help. I can't go to fiddle in work, neither can a whole bunch of other SO users. But, primarily, SO requires the code to be in the question, so that if JSFiddle stops working the question is still readable and understandable. Your question is going to be closed if you don't fix it.

Comment: @biolarnative You posted a jsfiddle without posting code, which is specifically disallowed.

Comment: BTW: seriously... **why you have to design that on PhotoShop**??? That CSS is good only if consumed by...PhotoShop itself.

Comment: @j08691 OK I wrote the code in the question, now can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be a better approach.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/j9wU9/

```
#alert_strip p {
 text-align:center;
 width:778px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 color:#f2f2f2;
 overflow:hidden
}

#alert_strip span {
 float:right;
 width:538px;
 text-align:center;
} 

h4{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-size:37px;
 font-weight:400;
 float:none;
 background:0
}
```

When it comes to images - `float: left` image one and `float:right` image two

Comment: Hi, this is what i saw after edit to your code:
http://prntscr.com/439gvi

Whats wrong?

Comment: remember to remove the inline css that you have in your html file `style="position: fixed; margin-top: -76px; opacity: 1;"`

Comment: you must have something else in your css code then. Do a inspect element or use firebug to see what property is causing the problem. The JSFiddle is working properly.

Comment: No i dont have anything else. I put all the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WRWZ9/

And i see its working, but in my server its show this:
prntscr.com/439gvi

What is the problem?

Comment: Remove the `height: 100%;` property for the `<i>` and the `<a>` element.

Comment: Done, but now the images are gone:
http://prntscr.com/439s7d

How can i bring them back?

Comment: instead of the `height: 100%;` put the actual `height` of the image.

Comment: For the `<a>` element, when i put 10px in `height`, its look likes: http://prntscr.com/439w4d . 

for `<a>` element, when i put large number, the background is going bigger: http://prntscr.com/439wqe

What can i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57425/discussion-between-biolarnative-and-rob).